# .NET: Possible to change XPath() expression based on URL parameters?

Tags: .net, xpath, filter

I'm setting up a simple page that just displays the contents of an XML file and allows the user to filter by keyword.

I'm a serious .NET newb, but I've got an XmlDataSource set up:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="RSSFeedDataSource" runat="server"  DataFile="test.xml"
        XPath="/rss/channel/item[contains(title,"theKeyword")]"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

So I want to allow users to type in a keyword and change the data source based on that.

I figured I'd do a postback with the keyword from a text input, grab that keyword and somehow insert into the XPath expression...

I'm going for simplicity at this point, but would this be the simplest approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method to grab it via code behind and a button postback

ASP Page:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtKeyword" runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="btnKeyword" OnClick="btnKeyword_Click" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
public void btnKeyword_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Assuming C#
  // Retrieve the keyword from the text box
  string keyword = txtKeyword.Text

  // Next step would be to modify the XPath of your XmlDataSource
  RSSFeedDataSource.XPath = "/rss/channel/item[contains(title," + keyword + ")]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it from within the page itself, like so:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="RSSFeedDataSource" runat="server" 
  DataFile="test.xml"
  XPath="/rss/channel/item[contains(title,"<%=Request.QueryString["filter"] %>")]"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

If that doesn't work, why not just set the XPath property in the code-behind using the query string or post values?

Answer (score 0):

on the postback, you should be able to do

```
RSSFeedDataSource.XPath = "/rss/channel/item[contains(title,'" + txtKeyword.Text + "')]";
```

assuming the keyword is coming from a server control with id txtKeyword